# Inserting into Hive table - Non Partitioned table to Partitioned table - Cannot insert into target table because column number/types

Tags: hadoop, hive

**When I tried to insert into a Partiotioned table I am getting the bellow error 
SemanticException [Error 10044]: Line 1:23 Cannot insert into target table because column number/types are different ''US'': Table insclause-0 has 2 columns, but query has 3 columns.**

**My Input data**

```
1,aaa,US
2,bbb,US
3,ccc,IN
4,ddd,US
5,eee,IN
6,fff,IN
7,ggg,US
```

**Created hive table tx**

```
create table tx (no int,name string,country string) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';
```

*Created Partitioned table t1 **partitioned by country***

```
create table t1 (no int,name string) PARTITIONED BY (country string)  ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';
```

***I tried the bellow two insert, but failed***

```
    INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE t1 PARTITION (country='US') 
SELECT *   from tx where country = 'US';

    INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE t1 PARTITION (country='US') 
SELECT no,name,country from tx where country = 'US';
```

**Error** *: SemanticException [Error 10044]: Line 1:23 Cannot insert into target table because column number/types are different ''US'': Table insclause-0 has 2 columns, but query has 3 columns.*

Comment: RTFM -- Hive is not Oracle. In Hive the partitioning "columns" are managed as **metadata** >> they are not included in the data files, instead they are used as sub-directory names. So your partitioned table has just 2 real columns, and you must feed just 2 columns with your SELECT.

Comment: On the other hand, if you used *dynamic partitioning* -- i.e. `INSERT ... PARTITION (country)` with no literal value -- then the actual value for the partitioning "column" would have to be fed as an *extra* column in SELECT, after the real columns.

Comment: Thanks a ton Samson Scharfrichter. Yes it worked..... I posted the right query ....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**A Big Thanks to  Samson Scharfrichter**

```
    INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE t1 PARTITION (country='US') 
SELECT no,name  from tx where country = 'US';
    INSERT INTO TABLE t1 PARTITION (country='IN') 
SELECT no,name  from tx where country = 'IN';
```

***I checked the Partitions***

```
hive>  SHOW PARTITIONS t1;
OK
country=IN
country=US
Time taken: 0.291 seconds, Fetched: 2 row(s)
hive>
```

Comment: I see. So basically, don't use * and don't place the partition column itself. Thanks!